# Brushing hair alternative word or phrase?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

It seems like it should be simple enough but the English language fails me again. Can you find a word or phrase that means "brushing (enter possessive pronoun) hair" or "to brush one's hair" without using the word brush or comb?

And if that is impossible, what is another word or phrase that has the same meaning?

**Examples:**
*She sits before the mirror to **brush her hair** each day.*

*Margaret will **brush their hair** exactly 100 times to get the perfect shine.*

Comment: Why can't you use the words "brush" or "comb"?

Comment: Sorry, we need this other verb why?

Comment: You want a word referring specifically to brushing it lots of times (100 times), as was done in olden days (apparently this has specific benefits if you don't wash it often, removing dirt and distributing oil, but is less beneficial in the era of modern hair care)? Rather than a word for styling it, prettifying it, or otherwise shaping it, or combing it or back-combing it (often done with a brush!), or detangling or other things you might do to your hair?

Comment: Stuart F you got it in one. This is what my second example is referring to and why I am in search of an alternative word or phrase.

Answer (score 1):

You could say that she **did her hair.**

[TFD defines *do* in the relevant sense as:](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/do)

> to make tidy, elegant, ready, etc, as by arranging or adorning: *to do one's hair.*

Comment: Sorry, but....Hair is already combed or brushed out before being done.

Comment: Mother to schoolboy as he rushes out the front door: "Have you done your hair?"

Comment: Not quite what I am looking for. This phrase seems to more regard how you style your hair instead of what you do before you style it.

Answer (score 1):

You may want *she **preened** her hair*. Wordnik's third meaning for *preen* is *"To dress or groom (oneself) with elaborate care; primp."* [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/preen)

Comment: You preen _yourself_; I've never heard it used of one's hair.

Comment: Cats preen and if humans do, it sounds really weird.

Comment: Actually I now wonder if *primp* might be better. I was originally thinking of *preen* as an extension of birds preening their feathers, which is a fairly painstaking, though routine, process. When I checked the meaning on wordnik I found the meaning I cited, which appeared appropriate. When I think of a person preening themselves, I tend to think of the meanings that are related to *gloat* rather than the meanings associated with grooming.